# How to load Recycler view Faster With Firebase Database Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

So am Actually trying to make chat application which I made using Firebase so my problem is whenever an user opens the app it there's some delay in loading recycler view which makes it feel like the app is slow.
I have enable `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` It improved a little but the problem is not fixed when I check logcat for some time it says Adapter not attached to layout then it loads is there anyway to load it instantly like in whatsapp whenever I open its already there so is there anyway to increase the performance

Comment: I guess whatsapp also stores instance locally using SQLite, that is why you can read all messages even offline.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: @AnkitMishra Even in Firebase I can read all messages in offline but yeah whatsapp uses SQLite maybe thats why its much faster Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Yes true.. firebase has this feature too